# What to do after indexing and partitioning to improve performance

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, performance, performance-tuning

I have a large table with about 100 million rows.

I have done indexing and partitioning in the table, but still queries sometimes take >100 or even >200 seconds to run.

So I was thinking, what is the next step after indexing and partitioning to improvise the MySQL performance.

1. Changing the code logic is one option (but that is reducing the data, I am concerned about how to tune MySQL to work with this data only)
2. Upgrading the hardware and MySQL versions in another.(I am already using SSD, 8 core CPU and 32GBs RAM, and resources are available most of the time. )

And this question is not only about this table, but about general MySQL practices. Like doing indexing is one of the basic things, and after indexing second thing is partitioning. But what after that? My question can be little vague, but I think this will be helpful to many people searching for similar ansers.

To give you an idea, here is an overview of my table `large_table` :

```
+------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
| user | mobile     | is_first_time | time_send           |
+------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
| a    | xxxxxxxxxx | 0             | 2018-03-12 00:00:00 |
+------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
| b    | xxxxxxxxxx | 1             | 2018-04-02 07:08:09 |
+------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
| c    | xxxxxxxxxx | 0             | 2018-01-03 01:02:03 |
+------+------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Following is the output of `SHOW INDEXES FOR large_table`

```
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| large_table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | user        | A         |         493 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| large_table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | mobile      | A         |   105682194 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| large_table |          1 | userid   |            1 | user        | A         |      188718 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The four type of queries that generally run on this table :

`INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table (user,mobile) VALUES ('1234','9876543210')`

`UPDATE large_table SET is_first_time = 0 WHERE (user,mobile) IN(('xxxx','XXXXXXXXXX'),('zzzz','ZZZZZZZZZZ'),('yyyy','YYYYYYYYYY'),('aaaa','AAAAAAAAAA')`

`SELECT mobile FROM large_table WHERE user = 168807`

`SELECT count(mobile) FROM large_table WHERE  user =xxxx`

Thanks in advance
(this is more of a knowledge-seeking question rather than problem's solution)

DDL of table: https://gist.github.com/kadambkaluskar/4e2ff8d5be6f625c123b58bc10cb32b0

Edit 1: Couldn't run EXPLAIN on UPDATE query, as I am using MySQL 5.5

Edit 2:

Whenever there is a query like `` UPDATE large_table SET is_first_time = 0 WHERE (`user`,`mobile`) IN ``, it goes into `updating` state, and all other queries start to line-up after that.

Following is the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

```
+------------+---------+------------------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id         | User    | Host             | db     | Command | Time | State      | Info                                                                                                 |
+------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1307948736 | my_user | 10.0.0.48:29134  | my_db  | Query   |   91 | Updating   | UPDATE large_table SET is_first_time = 0 WHERE (`user`,`mobile`) IN(('21xx67','919xxxxxx002'),('2177 |
| 1308045382 | my_user | 10.0.0.62:42912  | my_db  | Query   |   50 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('9xx75','917xxxxxx805')                          |
| 1308064919 | my_user | 10.0.0.48:56362  | my_db  | Query   |   42 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('105xx7','9189xxxxxx59')                         |
| 1308066190 | my_user | 10.0.0.21:63342  | my_db  | Query   |   41 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('91xx0','9196xxxxxx60')                          |
| 1308069898 | my_user | 10.0.0.62:48648  | my_db  | Query   |   39 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('95xx5','9192xxxxxx14')                          |
| 1308073279 | my_user | 10.0.0.88:30996  | my_db  | Query   |   38 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('57xx4','9170xxxxxx43')                          |
| 1308073424 | my_user | 10.0.0.24:4738   | my_db  | Query   |   38 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('91xx0','919xxxxxx494')                          |
| 1308073776 | my_user | 10.0.0.88:31118  | my_db  | Query   |   38 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('11xxx3','919xxxxxx224')                         |
| 1308076906 | my_user | 10.0.0.72:26482  | my_db  | Query   |   37 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('1xx17','9197xxxxxx62')                          |
| 1308077527 | my_user | 10.0.0.9:28928   | my_db  | Query   |   37 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('76xx0','9198xxxxxx66')                          |
| 1308082112 | my_user | 10.0.0.113:4230  | my_db  | Query   |   34 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('10xxx8','9197xxxxxx60')                         |
| 1308083588 | my_user | 10.0.0.72:27516  | my_db  | Query   |   34 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('11xxx4','919xxxxxx557')                         |
| 1308088011 | my_user | 10.0.0.101:60448 | my_db  | Query   |   32 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('12xxx0','9184xxxxxx48')                         |
| 1308090557 | my_user | 10.0.0.9:32118   | my_db  | Query   |   31 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('11xxx0','9193xxxxxx59')                         |
| 1308093171 | my_user | 10.0.0.72:29535  | my_db  | Query   |   30 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('11xx84','9193xxxxxx07')                         |
| 1308095347 | my_user | 10.0.0.113:5454  | my_db  | Query   |   29 | Updating   | UPDATE large_table SET is_first_time = 0 WHERE `user`=12xxx1 AND `mobile` = '917xxxxxx482'           |
| 1308096238 | my_user | 10.0.0.62:56668  | my_db  | Query   |   29 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('10xxx8','9190xxxxxx03')                         |
| 1308096342 | my_user | 10.0.0.78:16782  | my_db  | Query   |   29 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('1xxx6','9193xxxxxx54')                          |
| 1308106957 | my_user | 10.0.0.100:17930 | my_db  | Query   |   25 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('7xxx8','9189xxxxxx33')                          |
| 1308109743 | my_user | 10.0.0.107:29496 | my_db  | Query   |   23 | update     | INSERT IGNORE INTO large_table(user,mobile) VALUES ('1xxx29','9197xxxxxx75')                         |
+------------+---------+------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Userwise mobile distribution :

```
+-------------+----------------+
| no.of.users | mobile.no.count|
+-------------+----------------+
|      1      |   1.5milion    |
|      2      |   1 milion     |
|      10     |   500-1000k    |
|     147     |   100k-500k    |
|     173     |   50k-100k     |
|    1336     |    10k-50k     |
|    2610     |     5k-10k     |
|    6500     |     1k-5k      |
|     12k     |     100-1k     |
|     12k     |     100-1k     |
|     10k     |     10-100     |
|     23k     |      1-10      |
+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: DDL of `large_table` - where is it? We need to look on additional fields, partition info, etc.

Comment: Also, which query needs 100+ seconds? Add the `EXPLAIN` output for that.

Comment: @Akina : https://gist.github.com/kadambkaluskar/4e2ff8d5be6f625c123b58bc10cb32b0

Comment: Which of these queries are taking > 100 seconds to run, all of them? On average, what number of mobiles do each user have? Is there a particular reason for treating int and bigint as strings (example: values ('1234','9876543210') )?

Comment: @Lennart : I have edited the question to include more details.

Comment: @Lennart : nope, there is no particular reason to use int and bigint as strings, and I don't know why they were there in first place. I am on my way to remove those quotes.

Comment: How many rows do you typically put in the where of the update, `IN ( ... )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `PARTITIONing` buys you no performance.  Get rid of it.  (Also, 400 partitions is so many that that, itself, slows things down.  [*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).)
- You already have this; keep it:

`PRIMARY KEY(user, mobile)`

- Change the `UPDATE`.  Although "row constructors" as in `WHERE(a,b) IN ((1,2),...)` is tempting syntax, it is awful at performance.  The Optimizer does not ([*until version 5.7.3*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html)) do anything useful with that.  It scans the entire table!  (Note how thek first `UPDATE` in the `PROCESSLIST` is at 91 seconds, and seems to be blocking all the other queries.)

One way to 'fix' the update is to build a table (`tmp`) with the `IN` items, then do a multi-table `UPDATE` with

```
WHERE large.user   = tmp.user
  AND large.mobile = tmp.mobile
```

and have `PRIMARY KEY(user, mobile)` on `tmp`.

The other solution to the Update is to upgrade to 5.6, then 5.7.  Anyway, 5.5 will soon be End-Of-Life'd.

- To save a little space, and a little speed, consider `DECIMAL(11)` for `mobile`.  It would take 5 bytes instead of `BIGINT`, which takes 8.
- Get rid of the redundant `KEY(user)`.  A rule:  If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't need `INDEX(a)`.  And `PRIMARY KEY` is Unique and a key`.
- Don't say `count(mobile)`, simply say `COUNT(*)`.  When you specify an expression, it checks that for being `NULL`, which is not relevant in your case.  Although `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lt WHERE user = xx` might use `INDEX(key)`, the overhead of that otherwise-unneeded index makes it *probably* not worth having.
- Be cautious about `MAX(user)`.  100M is not terribly far from 2 billion.  Note, making it `INT UNSIGNED` would raise the limit to 4 billion, while still taking only 4 bytes.

I hope I have provided you some 'knowledge' as well as multiple solutions toward improving the table's performance.

After all these suggestions, I suspect you will rarely see a `Time` greater than "1" in `PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: thank you for valuable suggestions. most knowledgeable is that partitioning is of no use in this case(and in any case, other than the four you have mentioned in many of your posts). i have started migrating my data to aws-aurora to use 5.7 features. one more question, which is better option in your opinion, aurora for mysql 5.7 or mysql-5.7 on RDS?

Comment: @kadamb - Sorry, I do not have enough info on those two to give an opinion.  Anyway, the diffs would probably be application-dependent.

Comment: just upgrading my system to 5.7 solved all the long-running queries. :)

Comment: @kadamb - Glad to hear that 5.7 helped.  The rest of my suggestions may help, but to a lesser degree.